# Get Taxonomy and metadata

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have this code that get the list of my taxonomy:

```
 $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
    );

    $nations = get_terms( 'nation', $args );
```

I also need to get all the metadata associated for each element, how can I do that?

`$nation` is a `WP_TERM` object but I do not have any information in it.

I also tried to use:

```
var_dump(get_term_meta($nation->term_id));
```

but it says that the object is empty.

Answer (score -2):

```
$terms = get_terms( 'my_taxonomy' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $all_term_meta=get_term_meta($term->term_id);

    }

}
```

Comment: I get `array (size=0)  empty` if I try to `var_dump($all_term_meta)`

Comment: my data is saved in `wp_options`

Comment: Please post a proper answer. Please see [answer] and use that as a guide to write a proper answer. Just simply dumping code is a poor answer. No wonder the OP can't make head or tail of what you posted.